# How to customize the appearance of the Facebook Share Button in the SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been all over the internet and can't seem to get a direct answer or tutorial, so this is my final attempt to get an answer.

I have an android app integrated with Facebook SDK.  I added a share button, but I don't like the look of it.  I've seen other apps with different looking Facebook share buttons, but for some reason I don't see any doc on how to do it.  I tried changing the .png in the drawable folder of the Facebook SDK but that didn't work.

Anytime I would assign my own .png, it will render on top of a native appearance.

Can someone help step by step.  It would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own Button with your desired look.

Then apply on onClick the share action.
 You can use a ShareIntent for example

```
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, imageUri);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.label_share)));
```

The main idea is not to try to change the look of the share button that facebook sdk provides but to add the share functionality to your own button.

Comment: This code doesn't allow images...I need to share text and images to the timeline.

Comment: You can use it for image too but you need to use this: shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");